# Let $G/H$ be any quotient group and $a^r, a^s$ elements of $G$. If $x \in a^rH \cap a^sH,$ then is $r = s$?

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

I have the following case: Let $G/H = \langle aH \rangle$ be any quotient group and $a^r, a^s$ elements of $G$. If $x \in a^rH \cap a^sH,$ then is $r = s$?

Well, I thought of this: if $x \in a^rH \cap a^sH,$ then $a^rH \cap a^sH \neq \emptyset.$ So $a^rH = a^sH$. I stopped here and I'm not getting such equality.

If $G/H$ is cyclic, do we have the result?

Comment: You were right to stop there. Let $t=r-s$, it may happen that $a^t\in H$ (or even $a^t=1$) and $t\ne0.$

Comment: This is never true in a finite group. Let $G$ be any group (e.g., $G$ is trivial), let $H$ be any normal subgroup, let $a$ be any element. Then $a^n=1$ for some $n\in \mathbb Z$, and so $a=a^{n+1}$. Certainly then $aH=a^{n+1}H$. The only time it is true is if $aH$ has infinite order in $G/H$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $xH\in G/H$ have order $n$. Then

$$\begin{align}
x^{n+m}H&=(xH)^{n+m}\\
&=(xH)^n(xH)^m\\
&=e_{G/H}(xH)^m\\
&=(xH)^m\\
&=x^mH
\end{align}$$

for all $m\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of knowledge, but I don't understand why you wrote this. Can you help me?

Comment: Let $s=a$, $n=r$, and $m\in \Bbb Z\setminus \{0\}$ such that (your) $s=n+m$, @user163733.

Comment: I have changed notation for clarity, @user163733.

Comment: Better yet: let $x=a, n=2, m=1$; then  $$a^3H=aH,$$ @user163733.

Comment: If $G/H$ is cyclic, do we have the result?

Comment: No, @user163733. Consider $K:=G/H\cong \Bbb Z_2$. Then $K$ has exactly one nontrivial element, say $kH$. Then $k^3H=kH$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, @user163733, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: What if $G/H= \mathbb{Z}_n$? Do we have the result?

Comment: No, @user163733; in that case, we have $$a^{n+1}H=aH.$$

Comment: What's the first thing you don't understand about my answer to your initial question, @user163733?

Comment: If $G/H$ is infinite and cyclic, and $G=\Bbb Z$, then the result holds true, @user163733. This is because there is no *torsion*.

Answer (score 0):

Here the group being a quotient is not essential for your question. Basically you are asking: let $G$ be a group, and $g\in G$, $m,n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $g^m=g^n$. Does it implies $m=n$? Well, if $g=e$ certainly not, as then $g^m=g^n$ holds *for every* pair $(m,n)$. Let's then suppose $g\ne e$. Now, $g^m=g^n \iff$ $g^{m-n}=e$. If $g$ has finite order $o(g)$, then this just implies $o(g)\mid m-n$, not else (let alone $m=n$). If $g$ has infinite order, then the implication holds true, as by definition of infinite order there isn't any (least) positive integer $k$ such that $g^k=e$. So your implication holds true if $G\cong\Bbb Z$. Now think of $G$ here as your "$G/H$": the claim holds true if $G/H\cong\Bbb Z$ and $a\notin H$ (this latter to mimick my "$g\ne e$").

Comment: What if $G/H = \langle aH \rangle$? do we have the result?

Comment: Yes, if and only if $aH$ has infinite order, @user163733.

Comment: In fact, if $o(H)$ is finite, then $a^{o(H)+k}H=a^kH$. On the other hand, if $o(H)$ is infinite, then $a^kH=H\iff k=0$.